# What are the justifications and historical reasons regarding the choice between the words 'calculus' and 'algebra'?

Tags: terminology

The principles of calculus, historically, are differentials and integrals [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus), while those of algebra are operators and equation solving [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra). Contemporary principles are analysis and abstract objects, respectively.

As an example case, why is relational algebra not called a calculus, and why is the π-calculus not called an algebra?

Comment: Sometimes, names just fall out of the sky and stick. Why "dynamic programming"? (Answer: marketing trick) Why "red-black trees"?

Comment: @AlexisPetrounias, as far as I can tell, a calculus is supposed to refer to a system of rules/algorithms for symbolic manipulations, whereas an algebra is supposed to refer to a structure imposed on data (unless it is just an [algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_(ring_theory))). So I don't think we can draw a universal distinction because in a calculus the objects of computation must be represented somehow and in an algebra the manipulation of the data must be subject to rules. So it would just be a question of where the emphasis lies. There's some history on the math.se post.

Comment: I have deleted some comments here. Please take discussion regarding this question to the CS chat rooms and/or Meta site to discuss the site's policy and/or the closing of this question. If you can find a way to incorporate feedback on this question such that you feel it becomes appropriate, pleas feel free to flag the question for moderator attention. Thanks for your cooperation and for contributing to the site!

Comment: voting to reopen at _raphaels_ suggestion in chat! its maybe not the greatest question in the world _(which ones are?)_ but the question is clearly on topic about [tag:terminology] of _computer science!_ but maybe the title is misleading & closers thought its more a math question? some significant amt of terminology of CS is borrowed from math of course.... my analogy/metaphor has been something like "algebra is checkers, calculus is chess"... imho FSM/regular languages are at times something like the "algebra" of CS

Comment: Cheers @vzn, what do you suggest the title be changed to? On my part there is absolutely no uncertainty on the mathematical meaning of these terms. I asked this question because, for the past few years, every time I speak with physicists and theoretical mathematicians about computing they are confused when we call something a calculus as opposed to an algebra. I have not been able to offer a compelling answer for how these terms transfer from mathematics to computing, and how we chose to call one model a calculus and another an algebra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is in a name? Calculus is called *analysis* in some  languages
other than English, while the word *calculus* itself means computation.

The name π-calculus was most likely chosen by Milner because it has
to do with computation, and is intended to be for parallel computation
similar to what $\lambda$-calculus is for classical sequential computation.
Computation is actually the original meaning of calculus,
referring to pebbles used as counters in ancient time.

The word *algorithm*, as everyone knows, comes from the name
*al-Khwarizmi* (the man from Khiva, a city formerly called [Khwarezm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khwarezm)), given to the 9th century Persian
mathematician [Abū Ja‘far Muhammad ibn Mūsa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu%E1%B8%A5ammad_ibn_M%C5%ABs%C4%81_al-Khw%C4%81rizm%C4%AB). *Algebra* comes from the
name of the treatise Hisab al-jabr wa'l muqabala, that he wrote about
the resolution of equations.

*Al-Khwarizmi systematized the study of equations (**algebra**), and gave
procedural techniques to solve them (**algorithms**), which implies some form of computation (**calculus**). Could this be seen
as a kind of Curry-Howard situation, where the mathematics for proving
go in hand with the corresponding algorithms to actually compute ?*

Names may be chosen for strange reasons, and their meaning evolves
along with the objects they initially denote. The internationalization of sciences also leads to different interpretations of words, as the same word (or its local variant) may have a different meaning in different country (and that is also true is other areas of language, possibly creating some awkward situations).

This issue has already been discussed on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54763).

---

**Further remarks**

Actually, according to wikipedia, *Analysis* is used in all languages,
English included, with the same meaning. English appears to use the
word *Calculus* which refers only to elementary concepts of Mathematical
Analysis, differential and integral calculus. If you look for the
English *Calculus* in wikipedia, you find out that translation is
missing for many languages (no equivalent entry in German or French
for example), and when an entry is proposed for another language it
may corresponds to a different meaning (*Cálculo* in Spanish is for
calculation or computation, as it is in some other languages).

However, *Cálculo* in Portuguese has the same meaning as in English and
covers the same topics. They actually explain, for Portuguese, the
origin of this use of the word, and the explanation is likely to be
the same in English. *Calculus* is very simply an abbreviation for
"*differential and integral calculus*". And indeed, it corresponds to
computations expressed with algorithms, and is, in this sense, close
to Algebra.

I was mislead, in understanding the question and writing the first
part of my answer, because I took *Calculus* to mean the whole of
Mathematical Analysis, as there is no single word in my own language
to cover specifically differential and integral calculus. Comments
show that I am not the only non-american user to be thus mislead.

Hence there is no linguistic inconsistency. The name *λ-calculus*
denotes a formalisation of algorithms and computation, and the use of
the word *calculus* is adequate. From it was derived the name *π-calculus*
for parallel computations.

Note that initially, *calculus* just means computation (*calculation* has
a connotation as pertaining to numbers). When applied to a specific
domain, it is qualified so that the domain is explicit (integral
calculus, π-calculus, ...). The problem comes from the fact that it
has a common use in some languages, including English and Portuguese,
where it is domain specific without making the domain explicit, while also retaining its more general use.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any languages which use the equivalent of 'analysis' for the English word 'calculus' which would also translate, say, π-calculus into the corresponding π-'analysis' in that language? From the Wikipedia entry for [π-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus) all translations currently available use the equivalent of 'calculus' not 'analysis' (e.g. Cálculo pi in French, Pi-Kalkül in Dutch, Пи-исчисление in Russian, and so on).

Comment: In German "Analysis" means "calculus". Note that "analysis" is "Analyse" in German so there is no ambiguity in that regard.

Comment: Al-Khwarizmi wasn't Arab, and his name doesn't mean the man from *Khiva*. Rather, he hails from Khwarizm, nowadays known as Khiva, a city in Uzbekistan, and had (apparently) Persian ethnicity.

Comment: Italian, for instance, makes the analisi/Calcolo distinction, so it's not just English. Also, Analysis can be used similarly in English. My point is that I don't see this as a very useful point...

Comment: Not to mention that calculus is also used to mean calculation/computation in everyday parlance, as in "that consideration did not enter into my calculus."

Comment: Note that I was careful never to say it was "just English".  I do not
have the information for Italian, but I was answering both comments
while you made the first remark, and I finished 15 minutes before the
second. The comment from the OP lead me to further investigation of
the question. But why comment an off-topic question (according to
you)?

Comment: Why not? Why do anything?

Comment: @Patrick87 Since you mentioned Italian, I checked [Calcolo (matematica)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcolo_%28matematica%29)
in wikipedia. And it is not too clear, with their awkward use of
parentheses, that they use the word alone in the English way, though
they say explicitly it is done in English. But from an Italian
mathematician I got confirmation that *Calcolo* alone is an abbreviation
as in English, but is actually very rarely used unlike English. Regarding the use in "*one's calculus*" it is nearly frozen use, that
is diverging semantically from the original meaning.

Comment: As a speaker of English and Italian, I disagree with your assessment of the words Calcolo (though I'd grant it's an abbreviation in the same way Calculus is an abbreviation, i.e., sort of) and calculus (referring to deliberation); in any event, even correct observations of such a nature are out of place on this site.