# What is different between "Arithmetic Calculation" and "Calculation" in computer science?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

What is different when you say "Arithmetic Calculation" and "Calculation" in the context of the computer science?

The "arithmetic" in the former seems needless to me since all calculations are arithmetic.

Is there some meaning that is enhanced by adding "arithmetic" in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Example: https://www.thunderstone.com/site/texisman/arithmetic_calculations.html

Comment: Example 2: General-purpose computers have the amazing property that a single piece of
hardware can do any computation imaginable. Before general-purpose computers
existed, there were special-purpose computers for arithmetic calculations,
which had to be manually reconfigured to carry out different calculations  (Principles of Programming Languages http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scott/pl/book/dist/book/book.pdf)

Comment: You should include a page reference for your second example. There are 189 pages in the pdf

Comment: Not all calculations are arithmetic (that is, deal with numbers). You can do symbolic calculations with variables on a computer, using for example Mathematica.

Comment: Even before *symbolic* calculations, you have things like `sin(pi)` which are *trigonometric* calculations.

Answer (score 2):

"Arithmetic calculations" are those involving addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of numbers. eg (2+13)/5

There are also "algebraic calculations"  eg Find y such that y + 2x = 13 and more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure my word processing program must do calculations, but since neither my input nor the results are expressed in numeric form, it hardly seems like arithmetic calculation. Is there an arithmetical operation called Insert, delete, or italicize? Of course, you could say these operations are reduced to arithmetical calculations, but in actuality, all calculations on a digital computer consist of combinations of and/or and nand/nor logic operations, some of which simulate arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

What the computer does is move electric charges around, change
magnetic state in some supports, read magnetic states, change some of
this into light pulses for transmission, and many others similar
microphysical manipulation.

Now it is up to you to interpret all that in whatever way you find
convenient, and give it a name accordingly.

Ignoring the physics, and going up one level, you manipulate bits. A
bit is just something that can have one of two possible states. All
that matters is that you can distinguish them. You may call them 0 and
1, or true and false, or Yin and Yan, or black and red, or up and
right.

Then there ways of manipulating them that encode  more complex things.
You can interpret a sequence of bits as a number, or as a letter, or
as a fragment of a text, or as a painting, or as a symphony. Your
choice, with appropriate encoding.

Then are you doing Arithmetic calculations, or composing music,
orwriting/reading a novel, or solving an equation ...?  It depends on
the encoding and the manipulation.

But it is always calculation, in a sense, Calculation comes from the
latin calculus : stone, as stones were initially used for counting
(which is indeed arithmetic). But what survived is the idea of
manipulating stones. And the name calculus is generally used to
indicate some form of manipulation of entities supposed to represent something, usually the manipulation of symbol
in the modern world.

So, yes, the computer does calculations. But that only means it is
pushing bits around. And it may be for any purpose, since it is a
universal way of representing information.

Note: The use of the word calculus alone to mean also diffential and
integral calculus is more a linguistic accident. See:
[What are the justifications and historical reasons regarding the choice between the words 'calculus' and 'algebra'?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22126/what-are-the-justifications-and-historical-reasons-regarding-the-choice-between)